# Can an Aboleth Enslave through its lair projection?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Per the description of Enslave, the [Aboleth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/aboleth) can use the ability on a creature it can see within 30 feet of it, but its projection lets it see and use telepathy from the new location. I assume it cannot use Enslave since it is not specified, but presumably it is a telepathic effect so I would like to check.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No, it can't.

Though the Aboleth can use telepathy from the projected image, that's referring to the "Telepathy 120ft." communication ability as listed in the languages section of its stat block - so, the Aboleth can telepathically converse at this increased range, and its *Probing Telepathy* special ability works as normal, since that doesn't specify a range. However, in order to use its magical enslaving ability, the target must be within 30ft of the real Aboleth.

You may want to note that nothing in the description of the Aboleth's *Enslave* action suggests that telepathy is required to produce the effect - though that would certainly be in keeping with the Aboleth's theme. As written, even a creature which is somehow prevented from sending or receiving telepathic communication is still vulnerable to the Aboleth's enslavement (presuming that whatever effect they are under doesn't also preclude being charmed).